# grails - can't use existing mysql field as id

Tags: grails

I have a existing mysql db table "Projects" with two rows:
Table:

```
project_id int(11) AI PK //(this is NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT)
name varchar(255) 
description varchar(255)
```

Rows:

```
1   test  testproject
2   dev   devproject
```

We would like to expose this as REST CRUD.

So I created a domain bean:

```
@ToString(includeNames = true, includeFields = true, excludes = 'dateCreated,lastUpdated,metaClass')
@EqualsAndHashCode
class Projects {
   int project_id 
   String name 
   String description

   static constraints = {
       name blank:false, nullable:false
   }

   static mapping = {
       table 'projects'
       version false
       id column:'project_id', sqlType:'int'
       project_id insertable:false, updateable:false
   }
}
```

Controller:
I ran autogenerate-controller and added

```
extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
```

so it looks:

```
@Transactional
class ProjectsController extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        respond Projects.list(params), model:[projectsInstanceCount: Projects.count()]
    }

    def show(Projects projectsInstance) {
        respond projectsInstance
    }

    def create() {
        respond new Projects(params)
    }

    @Transactional
    def save(Projects projectsInstance) {
        if (projectsInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (projectsInstance.hasErrors()) {
            respond projectsInstance.errors, view:'create'
            return
        }

        projectsInstance.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'projects.label', default: 'Projects'), projectsInstance.id])
                redirect projectsInstance
            }
            '*' { respond projectsInstance, [status: CREATED] }
        }
    }
}
```

When I do POST, I get error:

```
2014-06-14 23:48:07,678 [http-bio-8090-exec-2] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
Error |
2014-06-14 23:48:07,751 [http-bio-8090-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SQLException occurred when processing request: [POST] /passfarm/Projects
Field 'id' doesn't have a default value. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
    Line | Method
->> 1086 | createSQLException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
```

I found questions regarding similar questions but it did not work for me when I recreated schema.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How does the request payload look like? Also, do not use primitives in persistent entities (domain class) change `int project_id` to `Integer projectId`. `projectId` also has to be specified as the identifier, so `id name: 'projectId', column:'project_id', sqlType:'int'`

Comment: Thank You. Working with your suggestions.